# Firebase firestore WEB v.9 retrieve data ID-s from collection where that current user ID contains

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, where-clause

I am trying to retrieve specific data from firebase, in my redux store I have uniq id that I can get in any page like this

```
const currentUser = useSelector(selectLoggedInUser); 
console.log(currentUser.id) // "71dc954d-d2a4-4892-8257-98696fe776cd" this is peace of doc name in "dms" collection
```

**I want all doc-s that contains this ID** "71dc954d-d2a4-4892-8257-98696fe776cd", how can I query it???
This is how I'm setting "dms" messages

```
export const sentDirectMsg = async ({ toUid, currentUid, message, name }) => {
  const collecitonRef = await dmCollection(toUid, currentUid);
  await addDoc(collecitonRef, {
    timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
    message,
    name,
  });
};

const dmCollection = async (toUid, currentUid) => {
  const idPair = [currentUid, toUid].sort().join("_");
  return collection(db, "dms", idPair, "messages");
};
```

[image: from firebase firesotre]

I'm not enough clear sorry for that(just don't have enough experience), I'll try my best.
I'm trying to create Slack like app(I have many pages and function that I exporting from one place to another), I will show how I implement the channels messages sent & get from firebase, then explain how I make direct messages

```
//Function that sent message to exact channelId /channels/someChannelId/messages
// channelId is literal with dynamic id
export const sentMsg = async ({ name, message, channelId }) => {
  await addDoc(collection(db, "channels", channelId, "messages"), {
    timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
    message,
    name,
  });
}; 
//Getting data from channel
      const messagesRef = query(
        collection(db, `channels/${channelId}/messages`),
        orderBy("timestamp")
      );
      onSnapshot(messagesRef, (snapshot) => {
        setMessages(snapshot.docs);
      });
```

Now as I need DM I can't make it same way because it need some privacy, only 2 person should see the messages, so I need 2 uniq person that has uniq id and their collection of messages also is uniq(so that only they can see each other messages),in general when I register the users in my app I also save with them uniq ID for example this "71dc954d-d2a4-4892-8257-98696fe776cd",

```
//This is how I sent direct messages
// toUid - to whom I should sent
// currentUid - is who is sent
const sentDirectMsg = async ({
  toUid,
  currentUid,
  message,
  name,
}) => {
  const collecitonRef = await dmCollection(toUid, currentUid);
  await addDoc(collecitonRef, {
    timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
    message,
    name,
  });
};

const dmCollection = async (toUid, currentUid) => {
  const idPair = [currentUid, toUid].sort().join("_");
  return collection(db, "dms", idPair, "messages");
};
```

// As I'm sorting this two uniq ID-s from where person sent-s the message it is always same collection reference. **My question is can I somehow by "query" or by "where" get all docs that contains current user ID???**
[image: firestore]

Comment: When you say **that contains this ID**, where do you expect the ID to be stored?

Comment: It is already stored in firebase, if you look into the photo the last one doc has the same ID in the name. I just want the messages from that doc(that contains current user ID)

Comment: Could you add the messages collection data structure?

Comment: Sure I can read messages from there

Comment: I can't be of much help without having more insights on your data strucure. You mentioned that the use id is already your document key, while it seems like a compound one. What is the second compartment of your documents ids (user-id_XXX)?

Comment: ok I will add info on the top, just a sec

Answer (score 0):

If your data model is centered toward users being identified through their unique IDs, then you can store your data first hand to reflect his model:

```
const userData = {
  name: 'Marouane',
  state: 'BN',
  country: 'TUN'
};

// Add the user document in collection `dms`, with the id being the user ID
const res = await db.collection('dms').doc('71dc954d-d2a4-4892-8257-98696fe776cd').set(userData);
```

You can then query the user document using its unique identifier:

### Firebase v8

```
const userRef = db.collection('dms').doc('71dc954d-d2a4-4892-8257-98696fe776cd');
const doc = await userRef();
if (!doc.exists) {
  console.log('No such user!');
} else {
  console.log('User dms data:', doc.data());
}
```

### EDIT (Added firebase v9 - modular):

```
import { getFirestore, ref, onValue } from "firebase/firestore";

const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
const userRef = ref(db, 'dms/71dc954d-d2a4-4892-8257-98696fe776cd');
onValue(userRef, (snapshot) => {
  const data = snapshot.val();
  console.log(data);
});
```

In case your document id is not known in advance, you can query for all available documents and filter out ones that does not match your user id:

```
import { getFirestore, collection, query, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

const q = query(collection(db, "dms"));
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  if (doc.id.startsWith('71dc954d-d2a4-4892-8257-98696fe776cd')) {
    console.log(doc.data());
  }
});
```

Meanwhile, this approach will cause great performance degradation and would be better traded with a storage re-design.

Comment: Can you show me how it will look like in firebase version 9, a bit confusing for me.

Comment: I added an updated v9 approach along with a dynamic id identification for documents based on the user id.

Answer (score 0):

##### Edited:

If I understood correctly, you want to get a document which id contains a part of the id you are looking for.

Using [array-contains](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#array_membership) should do the trick:

```
const dmsRef = collection(db,"dms"); 
const docRef = query(dmsRef, where("idPair", "array-contains", id)); //for example id = "71dc954d-d2a4-4892-8257-98696fe776cd"

const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

if (docSnap.exists()) {
  console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
} else {
  // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
  console.log("No such document!");
}
```

I based my example on [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) from the official documentation.

Comment: in my case this "71dc954d-d2a4-4892-8257-98696fe776cd"  is only the part of doc, the full name of doc is look like this "71dc954d-d2a4-4892-8257-98696fe776cd_c51a0b24-bf1e-4b50-8deb-344476b97eb3" I just want to see is id of doc contains the part (71dc954d-d2a4 ...)

Comment: See if the edited answer does the trick for you